Passing $PATH from script execution to python
I am attempting to setup $PATH using a shell script and pass it to a python script. I have ShellWax in Eclipse and nodejs on my machine. I also have the plugin PyDev installed. I also have the debug perspective active for python. I execute the shell script that looks like:
!#/bin/bash
<shell commands to set up $PATH>
python <path to python script in workspace>

I have checked to ensure that path is setup properly at the end of the shell script execution before calling python and have set a breakpoint in the python code, which fires when the python script is called. However, when I print out the value of $PATH in the python script, the value of $PATH has completely changed. Is there a way to retain the values in $PATH between the shell script and the python script. It looks like PyDev resets $PATH when it gains control. There is a way to set $PATH manually using the environment tab of the debug configuration, but I need to transfer the value of the shell script $PATH to the PyDev debugger.
Added later in response to comments:
I am using a test bash script with the following contents:
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/$USER
pwd
source ~/.bash_test
echo $PATH
pyenv activate salt
python ~/SaltSource/3006.x/salt/scripts/salt-minion.py

.bash_test is the same as .bashrc, except the test for running interactively is removed, i.e., the following is removed:
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

The python script is:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
This script is used to kick off a salt minion daemon
"""

from multiprocessing import freeze_support

from subprocess import call
call ('echo "$SHELL"', shell=True)
call('echo "$PATH"', shell=True,)

import salt.utils.platform
from salt.scripts import salt_minion

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if salt.utils.platform.is_windows():
        # Since this file does not have a '.py' extension, when running on
        # Windows, spawning any addional processes will fail due to Python
        # not being able to load this 'module' in the new process.
        # Work around this by creating a '.pyc' file which will enable the
        # spawned process to load this 'module' and proceed.
        import os.path
        import py_compile

        cfile = os.path.splitext(__file__)[0] + ".pyc"
        if not os.path.exists(cfile):
            py_compile.compile(__file__, cfile)
    # This handles the bootstrapping code that is included with frozen
    # scripts. It is a no-op on unfrozen code.
    freeze_support()
    salt_minion()

The PATH value associated with the shell script right before the python execution (I had to put an exit 0 before the python call, since executing the script using the debugger goes right to salt-minion and resets the console) is shown in this screen shot:

The Path value after the python script is called is shown in this screen shot:

It appears PyDev clears out the environmental variables and sets Path to a value of its own. So, my question: is there a way to setup PyDev to keep the Path value associated with the Shell script?

What's the relevant python code? questions must provide a [mcve]

What happens if you use $PATH environment tab of the debug configuration?

In practice, PATH is always an exported variable (if it is not in your setup, just do a export PATH), and you can then access it in Python. Of course a Python programm itself can manipulate the environment, and Python code technically can indeed change the value of PATH. I don't know your Python script, but I suggest that you provide a minimal example which demonstrates your problem.

Note: $SHELL is not the currently running shell. "$SHELL" returns your login shell. call('echo "$0"', shell=True) probably reports /bin/sh

@glen jackman. Yes, you are correct. However, I added executable="/bin/bash" as a third argument to each subprocess call and call('echo "$0"', shell=True, executable="/bin/bash") returned /bin/bash. The output of call('echo "$PATH"', shell=True, executable="/bin/bash") remained the same, i.e., /app/bin:/usr/bin
